# Python Logarithm, Value Error : math domain error

Tags: python, math, python-module, logarithm

I am learning math with python, when I tried this code for logarithm it give me this error, any help ?

```
import math
n = 1000000
n2 = 0
for i in range(n):
    x = math.log2(i)
    n2 += x
print(n2)
```

it give me a value error : 
"ValueError: math domain error"

Comment: You are calculating `log2(0)`, which is `- inf`. Hence you are getting the error. Try `range(1,n)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import math
n = 1000000
n2 = 0
for i in range(1,n):
    x = math.log2(i)
    n2 += x
print(n2)
```

happy codeing !

Comment: It would probably be useful to explain why his code isn't working, code-only answers rarely help people fully understand where they went wrong vs, why your code does work.

Answer (score 1):

The range(n) is from 0 to  n-1
But Log(0) is not defined hence use range(1,n) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating `log2(0)`, which is `- inf`. Hence you are getting the error. Try `range(1,n)`.